# Knex.js return transactionScope in promise

Tags: node.js, apollo, knex.js, apollo-server

I've got a function setClaims which is simply setting claims for current transaction. I need to create a helper function which will check if uuid was provided, set claims and return the transaction object. Something like this:

```
export const useAuthTransaction = async (
  kx: Knex,
  setClaims: (tx: Knex.Transaction, uuid?: string) => Promise<any>,
  uuid?: string,
): Promise<Knex.Transaction> => {
  if (!uuid) {
    throw { errorCodes: [RemoveQuestionErrorCode.Unauthorized] };
  }

  return kx.transaction(async tx => {
    await setClaims(tx);
    return tx;
  });
};
```

But when I try to use it in my resolver:

```
useAuthTransaction(kx, setClaims, claims?.uid).then(async tx =>
  dataSources.questionAPI.update(tx, input));
```

it says:

> Transaction query already complete

How do I resolve transaction context without closing it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Returning promise from transaction handler automatically commits / rejects it.

So you are using `async tx => {...}` type of handler which implicitly always returns a promise.

What you want to do is to use the `knex.transactionProvider()` feature (check examples from docuementation) and then you can pass that transaction around and tell explicitly when it should be committed / rolled back.

Comment: This is exactly what I need. Thank you!